# Cold Conditioning in carboy vs keg

Tags: beer, conditioning, keg, carboy, cold

I have a wheat and a golden ale, both in 5 gal carboys, that have been in secondary fermentation for 2 weeks. I was planning on letting them settle for another week and then transferring them to kegs for 2 weeks of cold conditioning before carbonating.

Should I cold condition them in the carboy or would it be better to cold condition in the keg? If I cold condition in the keg will it hurt to also carbonate at the same time or would be better to carbonate after 2 weeks of conditioning?

I have never cold conditioned before am an not sure what to do. I am leaning toward cold conditioning them in the keg so I can bleed out any oxygen with a little Co2.

Comment: The wheat should be carbed and drank.  No need for more conditioning on that one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It makes absolutely no difference in the quality of the beer which way you do it.  I'd tend to do it in the keg for the reasons you mention.  You can carb it and have it ready to serve when it's done conditioning.